# How i can do the some things in get/post python

Tags: python

i write my code in method post , I need to do the some thing  in get method without writing the some code, it is possible to redirect from get method to post method

Comment: put your common code in functions, and call them as needed...

Comment: thanks, it is the only method to do this ?

Comment: Without more information regarding your setup, it's hard to say. Please [edit] your question with information regarding what framework you're using, how the user is calling the GET/POST methods from the HTML, and sample code of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve code re-use through abstraction.  Functions are a fundamental way to achieve abstraction.